# Docker -v parameter detail

Tags: docker, shell

I am dealing with this parameter, when entering a docker image.

```
-v $(pwd):/mnt/myFiles
```

I know that the `-v` flag maps a directory outside the container - on the docker host - to a directory inside the container.

```
-v /opt/datadir:/var/lib/mysql
```

The first parameter is the directory on out system (the docker host) and the second one the directory inside the docker container.

This is an example of how it's used. But in my case, the first parameter (my system - the docker host) is `$(pwd)`.

So what is going on exactly here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pwd`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pwd) is a Linux command.
It means: print me the current directory, as its acronym says it: **p**rint **w**orking **d**irectory.

`$()` means that instead of printing it back, we want to make a variable of the output of a command, that would otherwise print to stdout.

So, `-v $(pwd):/var/lib/mysql` actually means that you want to mount the current directory over `/var/lib/mysql`.